# How to make two db query synchronous, so that if any of them fails then both fails in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, asynchronous

```
     async.parallel([
      function(callback){ 
         con.Attandance.insert({'xxx':'a'}, function(err,data) {
            console.log(data);            
            callback();
        });
     }, function(callback) { 
         console.log(data);
        con.Profile.insert({'xxx':'a'},function(err){callback()});
     }
 ], function(err) { 
    console.log('Both a and b are saved now');
 });
```

Attendance.insert() works either Profile.insert() execute or fails. I want if any of them fails data should not be saved in any collection either in Attendance or in Profile

Comment: That's not what synchronous means.

Comment: So if the second query fails, you want to revert the first one?

Comment: I simply want, if any of the query fails the second should fail too.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean are [transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/), which have nothing to do with synchronous / asynchronous.

Unfortunately, MongoDB simply does not support transactions. The only way to achieve something even remotely close, you have to perform either a [two phase commit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/), or implement a custom rollback logic to undo all changes to `Attandance` if the changes to `Profile` failed.

The only possibility to at least achieve atomic (yet not transactions!) updates, is by changing your model. If the `Profile` is a container for all `Attandance` instances, you can update the entire object at one. It's impossible to update more than one object atomically with MongoDB, and neither is it possible to achieve a strict order of transactions.

If you need that, go for an SQL database instead. Pretty much all (except SQlite) support transactions.

Comment: My bad, i didn't checked the tags. Wasn't aware it was `MongoDB`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library that implements the two phase commit system (mentioned in a prior answer) described in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/). It might help in this scenario. [Fawn - Transactions for MongoDB](https://github.com/e-oj/Fawn).

```
var Fawn = require("Fawn");

// intitialize Fawn
Fawn.init("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/testDB");

/**
optionally, you could initialize Fawn with mongoose

var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/testDB");
Fawn.init(mongoose);
**/

// after initialization, create a task
var task = Fawn.Task();

task.save("Attendance", {xxx: "a"})
  .save("Profile", {xxx: "a"})
  .run()
  .then(function(results){
    // task is complete 

    // result from first operation
    var firstUpdateResult = results[0];

    // result from second operation
    var secondUpdateResult = results[1];
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    // Everything has been rolled back.

    // log the error which caused the failure
    console.log(err);
  });
```